# How to get skype status programmatically?

Tags: skype

I want to create a small console application to return current Skype status of the local Skype application if it's running (online / away / do not disturb / invisible / offline) and write history of its changes to the text file.

How can I do this? Where to start?

Comment: "Where to start?" - perhaps start by specifying the platform/OS and the programming language.

Comment: @H2CO3 Windows, Linux. Programming language doesn't matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Skype4Py for this:

https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py

It has GET/SET USERSTATUS command

http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference#COMMANDS

Comment: Skype4py doesn't seem to work for Android right?

Comment: This answer is more than 10 years old. Skype4py likely does not exist at all.

Answer (score 5):

### tl;dr;

The status checking URL is gone, your best bet is [the API](https://dev.skype.com).

### Details

There is an API aimed at web developers integrating call functions on their sites. It seems highly restricted, completely missing status-checking and a lot of other functions from the old API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx

Microsoft removed support for the old developer API at the end of 2013. A status-checking URL (`http://mystatus.skype.com/[username].txt`) was in place until early 2019. It is **no longer available**.

It required the Skype user to actively enable status checking from the web (it seems to be disabled by default). It could be enabled in `Preferences -> Privacy` by ticking `Show my status on the web` as of Skype version 6.19. If it was not enabled, the user would be shown as Offline.

Comment: Under what conditions does the status-checking URL give false information? It still seems to behave as expected (provided you've told Skype to report your status).

Comment: Yes, you're right! I didn't realize that. None of my Skype contacts had enabled this feature, so they all showed up as Offline.

Comment: This service is no longer in DNS